# Потоки на языке С

Tags: c, многопоточность

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что означает функция `thread_enqueue` в потоках? Язык программирования С.

Comment: Насколько я могу судить, нет такой стандартной функции в `c`. Всё, что находит гугл - это какие-то поделки для моделирования многопоточности. Функция используется для добавления объекта потока в очередь потоков.

Comment: Это для windows? Там все еще не перенесли pthreads?

Comment: to alexolut: спасибо!
to avp: нет, это для Linux.

Comment: А какой заголовок вы подключаете для работы с потоками?

Comment: Насколько знаю, такой стандартной функции нет. Ознакомиться со стандартными в Linux можно начав с [man 7 pthreads](http://linux.die.net/man/7/pthreads). Если Вы имеете в виду `thread_enqueue()` [вот тут](http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~jones/opsys/threads/source.txt), то это просто вспомогательная функция, перемещающая поток из активного состояния в одну из очередей диспетчера потоков (это "потроха" какой-то из реализаций потоков на user-level)